# Is there a maximum character length for a someobject.key.urlsafe()?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have an object stored in datastore. Is there a maximum character length for the objects key.urlsafe() ? I cannot seem to find the answer in the docs anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The length varies according to the key components and the length of the key.  It is a base-64 encoding of each `(Model, Id)` pair in the ancestor list.  The maximum character length is roughly the total length of the model name(s) and id(s) converted to base-64.

You can look for `def urlsafe` in the [Source code for google.appengine.ext.ndb.key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key)